# Unable to parse JSON data due to errors or undefined data

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I apologize if this seems similar to other questions asked but I have not been able to find any posts that have resolved this issue for me.  Basically, I am getting a JSON object and I am trying to parse it but I can't parse it correctly.  Mainly the WordDetails section that I am getting from a Word API.  I am able to get everything outside the results section under WordDetails.  Basically, when I get to results, I am not able to parse it correctly.  Below is an example of the format.

```
{
  "LastIndex": 133,
  "SRDWords": [
    {
      "Domain": {
        "URL": "abactinal.com",
        "Available": true
      },
      "WordDetails": "{\"word\":\"abactinal\",\"results\":[{\"definition\":\"(of radiate animals) located on the surface or end opposite to that on which the mouth is situated\",\"partOfSpeech\":null,\"antonyms\":[\"actinal\"]}],\"syllables\":{\"count\":4,\"list\":[\"ab\",\"ac\",\"ti\",\"nal\"]}}"
    },
    {
      "Domain": {
        "URL": "aaronical.com",
        "Available": true
      },
      "WordDetails": "{\"word\":\"aaronical\",\"syllables\":{\"count\":4,\"list\":[\"aa\",\"ron\",\"i\",\"cal\"]},\"pronunciation\":{\"all\":\"ɜ'rɑnɪkəl\"}}"
    },
...
```

Here is my code below.  Basically, I am getting to the results section of WordDetails but if I try to parse the results section it fails and if I try object.entries on it, it will not return a response according to the alert messages I used.  I know there must be a better way but not sure what.  Most articles say just JSON.parse then map it but that does not work.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
data.Words.map(word => {
    //get data
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(word)) {
        if (key === "Domain") {
            url = value.URL;
            availability = value.Available;
        } else if (key.trim() === "WordDetails") {
            alert("value " + value);
            wDetails = JSON.parse(value);

            for (let [key2, value2] of Object.entries(wDetails)) {
                if (key2 === "word") {
                    //store word
                } else if (key2.toString().trim() === "results") {
                    let test = JSON.parse(value2);
                    test = Object.entries(value2);
                    test.map(t => {
                        alert(t.definition);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please be more specific in the "does not work" statements, explain the error or undesired result you are getting

Comment: Sorry I do see that now.  I meant to say when I try to use Object.Entries on the results section of WordDetails, it will either not work or try to separate the string into an array of characters.  I want to extract the definition and synonyms but when I parse it, it will not allow me to do test.definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did JSON.parse above, no need to parse `value2` again.
And value for results is an array, so no need for `Object.entries`.

```
...

    } else if (key2.toString().trim() === 'results') {
      let test = JSON.parse(value2); // this should be remove
      test = Object.entries(value2); // this should be remove, value2 should be an array

      // map value2 directly
      value2.map(t => {
        alert(t.definition);
      });

    }

...
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!  So regarding value2, how can I tell what the property is?  For example, the JSON response may have multiple definition sections inside the results property.  I can get the value with t.definition using the value2.map but how can I go through and check each definition property?